# Send Array in post request using node.js using application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express

I tried to send post request to API and the post parameters should be array,
this is how to send it in cURL

```
curl http://localhost:3000/check_amounts
  -d amounts[]=15 \
  -d amounts[]=30
```

I tried to do that in Node.js using request module

```
request.post('http://localhost:3000/check_amounts', {
        form: { 
                'amounts[]': 15 ,
                'amounts[]': 30
              }
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(body)
        res.json(body);
    });
```

but the second amount override the first one and the API gets the result as following: `amounts = [30]`

Then I tried to send it in different way

```
 request.post('http://localhost:3000/check_amounts', {
            form: { 
                    'amounts[]': [ 15 , 30]
                  }
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            console.log(body)
            res.json(body);
        });
```

but the result was not as an expected `amounts = [{"0":15},{"1":30}]`

Note : the header should contains 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not 'application/json'

Does any one have solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you try: `'amounts': [ 15, 30 ]` ?

Comment: yes ... it will be considered as object ... it didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite easy if you read the manual of request. All you should do is replace the form by `querystring` rather than `object`, in your case this should be:

`amounts=15&amounts=30`

the only thing I'm not sure is the above expression works in your web server. As I know it works well in java `struts`. So if not you may try 
`amounts[]=15&amounts[]=30` instead. Hope it help.